# Laravel Query Builder How to Context Not Conditions

Tags: laravel, sql-update, toggle, query-builder

I have a laravel query

```
PasswordMovement::whereId($id)->update(['active' => '!active']);
```

my active field converts to 0 if it is 1. but if it is 0, it doesn't convert to 1?

Laravel Query Builder say to me, yes I create your query (with getQuerylog)

```
[
  {
    "query": "update `password_movement` set `active` = ? where `id` = ?",
    "bindings": [
      "!active",
      "10"
    ],
    "time": 0.5
  }
]
```

I changed the query as follows, the result still did not change, the query works successfully, but I don't get what I want.

```
PasswordMovement::whereId($id)->update(['active' => !'active']);
```

how can i update a field as toggle?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method **toggleActive** on the model itself.

```php
//PasswordMovement.php

public function toggleActive()
{
    $this->active = !$this->active;
    $this->save();

    return $this;
}
```

Then use this method in controller (or where ever else required)

```php
PasswordMovement::whereId($id)->first()?->toggleActive();

//Or if id is the primary key
PasswordMovement::findOrFail($id)->toggleActive();
```

###### Update

> also this method does not work in batch updates ::whereIn('id',$sid)->get() ->toggleActive();

For toggling active state of multiple records you can use higher order **each**

```php
PasswordMovement::whereIn('id', $sid)
    ->get()
    ->each
    ->toggleActive();
```

[Laravel Docs - Collections - Higher Order Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#higher-order-messages)

The **?** in `PasswordMovement::whereId($id)->first()?->toggleActive();` is **null safe operator** available since PHP 8

[PHP 8 Null Safe Operator](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-nullsafe-operator)

Comment: I vote reputation +1 but not affect , because my reputation less than 15, so I say thank you from comment .

Comment: PasswordMovement::whereId($id)->first()?->toggleActive();  
only, the question mark here works, but i don't understand what it means?
if you say it too, it will be perfect.

Comment: also this method does not work in batch updates
::whereIn('id',$sid)->get()
         ->toggleActive();

Comment: @poisonpawn Have updated the answer for batch updates and what is ?. Hope it helps.